# List inside Fragment on Creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm trying to create a list inside a fragment. I want a list where I can click the options so I can't edit its content, but for now I'm just trying to see something, which I can't.

I've been following http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/ but the truth is I'm getting error after error.

My code right now is:

```
 public static class PointsButtons extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listpoints, container, false);
            Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.createButton);
            final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
            String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                    "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                    "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
                list.add(values[i]);
            }
            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Fragment fragment = new PointCreation();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                }
            });

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    list.remove(item);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    view.setAlpha(1);
                                }
                            });
                }

            });
            return view;
        }
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> objects) {
            super(c, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Criar Ponto"
        android:id="@+id/createButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm having an error on this line:

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

The error is: 'com.example....app.MainActivity.this) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: If you have a crash, please post a stack trace from logcat

Comment: to get context in a fragment use `getActivity()`

Comment: I didn't runned it yet, since it's giving me an error I can't try to run it.

Comment: tyczj I'm using getActivy() the problem seems to be in here:

final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
error: 'com.example....app.MainActivity.this) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: your adapter is looking for `Context` and `this` is not context in a fragment. plus remove static from your class

Comment: it is giving me the same error with: final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

Comment: you need to not make your class static

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);



private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        private final Activity context;
        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.context = context;      
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to declare context in the StableArrayAdapter and initialize it in the constructor